# Animation nodes control for keyframes

Tags: keyframes, animation-nodes

I have a box that moves from point A to point B, by keyframes inserted. the same object has a AN applied for the rotation. I have conected the Combine Euler to a Time Info. I need help to find a way to start and stop the rotation on certain keyframes that i can choose. How do i do that?

Answer (score 3):

The *Delay Time* node can be used to make the animation starts at a certain frame while the *Duration* input in the *Animate Euler* node can be used to define the end frame such that the end frame is equal to the start frame plus the duration.